# How to connect to local IPv6 from separate newtork?

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding, ipv6

I have a Netgear Nighthawk R7000 router which I configured to use IPv6. Here is the output of **ifconfig -a** for my wireless card interface on my Linux machine.

```
wlp2s0b1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.1.8  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
    inet6 2601:81:c300:12f0:10c3:18be:20ef:b62c  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
    inet6 2601:81:c300:12f0:78ca:626a:14b3:c8a  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
    inet6 fe80::216d:afa5:e46e:6920  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether a4:d1:8c:65:4c:a4  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 1147508  bytes 762515013 (762.5 MB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 2  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 3752018  bytes 944468619 (944.4 MB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I was able to access a local web server I am hosting on **port 500** by accessing either of the two links

```
http://[2601:81:c300:12f0:10c3:18be:20ef:b62c]:500
http://[2601:81:c300:12f0:78ca:626a:14b3:c8a]:500
```

But now I am trying to access this web server from an external network. If this was IPv4 I would have to port forward and map my router's WAN IP and port to my machines LAN IP and port. How do I access my web server from another network with IPv6?

**Edit:**
Here are some of the possible firewalls and debugging info I have on my Linux machine:

Check to make sure IPv6 is enabled

```
# cat /sys/module/ipv6/parameters/disable
0
```

Check to make sure all IPv6 devices are enabled.

```
# sysctl -a 2>/dev/null | grep disable_ipv6
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 0
net.ipv6.conf.docker0.disable_ipv6 = 0
net.ipv6.conf.enp1s0f0.disable_ipv6 = 0
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 0
net.ipv6.conf.wlp2s0b1.disable_ipv6 = 0
```

Show any firewalls with iptable.

```
# sudo iptables -L -n
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-USER  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate             
RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
ACCEPT     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain DOCKER-USER (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
```

I could not see any relevant router firewall rules either.

Comment: You need to port forward (static NAT) your IPv6 address on your router.

Comment: @RonTrunk the static routes section of my router takes 3 inputs of destination ip, ip subnet mask, gateway ip, all of which seem to only be in IPv4 format. I do not see any option to use an IPv6.

Comment: If  your router can't do it, time for a new router.

Comment: It looks like your Linux box has a publicly routable IPv6 address. You should be able to connect to it from anywhere that you have IPv6 Internet connectivity.

Comment: @Spiff can you elaborate more? I have multiple devices with IPv6 capability, yet when they are on different networks they can not reach each other. I believe this is due to what Ron Trunk mentioned above.

Comment: @RonTrunk do you have any suggestions for routers or how to search? I am having some difficulty when searching for how to differentiate routers that simply support IPv6 and those that support IPv6 static NAT routes.

Comment: Requiring to use "static NAT" for IPv6 _doesn't make sense_, even more so when it's coming from a NetworkEngineering regular... If your router can forward the IPv6 packets, it can do so _regardless_ of whether they're NATed or not. There could definitely be some plain old firewall rules involved, however – have you checked those? (Both on your router _and_ on the devices themselves.)

Comment: According to your R7000's user manual, it seems that in the IPv6 settings there's a "Secured vs. Open" setting. The manual fails to define exactly what "Secured" really means, but I suspect "Secured" means "reject incoming IPv6 TCP connection attempts". Try setting it to "Open" instead. Beware that your R7000 doesn't seem to have a proper SPI firewall for IPv6, so changing this setting means your IPv6-capable devices on your home [W]LAN can get port scanned and attacked. So make sure they're all running their own software firewalls.

Comment: @Spiff yeah I read that as well in the manual but strangely enough, my router interface (which uses Netgear Genie), does not have that option in the IPv6 tab even though it says it should.